# How to jump over a space letter in a array, why doesnt my fix work?

Tags: java, arrays

So I've been trying to write this encryption program for 10 hours straight, and I think Iam close to be done but I've hit a brick wall.

When I write in single words everything works fine, but when iam trying to encrypt sentences it screws up. The reason for this is when there is a space between words no encryption should be done. I thought I could fix this easly by adding

```
if(vektor[k]== ' ') {
    k++;
}
```

My thought behind it was that it checks if the [k] is a space, and if it is i add +1 to k so I jump onto the next slot in my array.. But I get the errormsg  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` which I think means iam trying to look for a slot in the array that doesnt exist, but I dont know why it does this.

Here is my code, hope its all thats needed.

```
int k=0;
int Q=0;
while(x>0){

    if(Q>4){
        Q=0;     //resettar keyn till första bokstaven igen (räknar till 1-5)
    }

    vektor[k]=(char) (v[Q]+vektor[k]);
    if(vektor[k]>90){
        // System.out.println("STÖRRE ÄN 90 RESET");
        vektor[k]=(char)(vektor[k]-26);
    }

    Q++;
    System.out.print(vektor[k]);
    x--;
    k++;
    if(vektor[k]== ' '){
        vektor[k]='Ö';    
        k++;
    }

}
```

**edit**

I decided to add a new variable to make sure I didnt try and get out of the vector. I was happy when it worked at first. But when I try encrypt a text with two blanks, the encyrption fails. So I thought ye, I will just change the if(vektor[k]== ' ') to a while. But for some reason it doesnt work and I get the out of array error again.

This is my code now, it will work as long as you only get one ' ' between words.

```
int y=x;
            int k=0;
            int Q=0;
            while(x>0 && y>k){ //hur funkar y>k delen xDDDDD

                if(vektor[k]== ' '){
                    k++;
                    }

                if(Q>4){
                    Q=0;    //resettar keyn till första bokstaven igen (räknar till 1-5)
                    }

                vektor[k]=(char) (v[Q]+vektor[k]);
                if(vektor[k]>90){
                //  System.out.println("STÖRRE ÄN 90 RESET");
                vektor[k]=(char)(vektor[k]-26);
                }

                Q++;
                System.out.print(vektor[k]);
                x--;
                k++;


            }
```

Comment: you have a `while` looop checking for `x`, but the `if-statement` for `k` comes after using it as an indice. This is probably where your `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is steaming from. If you string is array is length 90 and `k==91`, you might get an error.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest **fix** you can do is to check after **incrementing k** if its value is bigger than your `vektor.length`

So after this part of your code:

```
x--;
k++;
```

Go ahead and add:

```
if(k>=vektor.length) break;
```

And after this part:

```
vektor[k]='Ö';    
k++;
```

Add it again (inside the if block):

```
if(k>=vektor.length) break;
```

This means that you will break out of the **while loop**. This is just a *fix to not get the **Exception*** you should still check the validity of your code (that it does as it is suppoused to do).

**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

In short it´s telling you that you are trying to access an invalid space of your array. When you create your array, you give it a length:

```
string[] vektor = new string[5];
```

If you do `vektor[5]` you will get the exception because the valid indexes for said vektor are 0,1,2,3,4 (if you count them, there are 5. Remember that arrays are 0-indexed, which means they start at 0).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `k` is going outside of the array; you need to add an additional check that `k` is less than or equal to the length of the vector.

Or if you're using x as the number of elements in the vektor remaining, then just make sure to put `x--` wherever you put `k++`.

In your code:

```
int k=0;
int Q=0;
    while(x>0){

        if(Q>4){
            Q=0;    //resettar keyn till första bokstaven igen (räknar till 1-5)
            }

        vektor[k]=(char) (v[Q]+vektor[k]);
        if(vektor[k]>90){
        //  System.out.println("STÖRRE ÄN 90 RESET");
        vektor[k]=(char)(vektor[k]-26);
        }

        Q++;
        System.out.print(vektor[k]);
        x--;
        k++;
        if(vektor[k]== ' '){
        vektor[k]='Ö';  
    k++;
    x--;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing this, in the case of a space you are jumping an extra character you will jump ahead to a position in the array which does not exist.

```
k++;
if(vektor[k]== ' '){
    vektor[k]='Ö';    
    k++;
}
```

Normally, this will increment `k` by `1` each time, but on the instance of a space it will increment `k` by `2` causing a leap which in the instance of for example the last character will now check the first past the last character.

I would suggest simply moving the `if` statement above your incrementing.

```
if(vektor[k]== ' '){
    vektor[k]='Ö';    
}    
Q++;
System.out.print(vektor[k]);
x--;

k++;
```

For example if your input is `test test`.  Your code will run fine until the last character `t` at which point it will encrypt it.  The next thing the code will do is increment it, now your index is out of bounds, then it makes the call to `if(vektor[k]== ' ')` which will return `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` because you have reached the end of your input, incremented, and checked again.